# Send a XML to a sp for insertion

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have a collection of myClass. I want to send it to a sp using XML. I dont know how to convert a collection to a xml.
After converting the collection to a xml, I want to send it to a stored procedure for bulk insertion

Please help

Comment: Are you dealing with XML only because you want to process all of the items in your collection with a call to one stored procedure?

Answer (score 3):

You can serialize your class to XML using the XmlSerializer, then pass that XML value into a stored procedure and then in the stored procedure iterate through the nodes.  Another option to pass in multiple rows of data besides XML would be to use [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) .

The XML approach would look something like this:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
{
    Encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, false)
};

StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();

using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(xml, settings))
{
    serializer.Serialize(xw, myClass);
}

...

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()
{
    CommandText = "InsertMyClass",
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
};

SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter()
{
    ParameterName = "@x",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Xml,
    Value = xml.ToString()
};

cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);

int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

For the sake of an example, assume that your XML looks like this:

```
<MyClass>
  <Item>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Property1>prop 1</Property1>
    <Property2>prop 2</Property2>
  </Item>
</MyClass>
```

Then a stored procedure could do the inserts:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertMyClass
( 
    @x XML 
) 
AS
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO table (ID, Prop1, Prop2)
  SELECT 
      CAST(CAST(r.i.query('./ID/text()') AS VARCHAR(20)) AS INT) ,
      CAST(r.i.query('./Property1/text()') AS VARCHAR(20)),
      CAST(r.i.query('./Property2/text()') AS VARCHAR(20))
  FROM   
      @x.nodes('/MyClass/Item') R(i)

END
```

Comment: Ugh!  There's no need to use a Cursor for this... :-(

Comment: @RBarryYoung -- yeah, I sort of said that there are probably better ways. Perhaps you could post a better answer or provide a link or even edit my answer if you want?

Comment: Maybe it's only me, but it just seems easier without the Cursor.  :-)

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I agree -- that looks much better!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) from serializing classes to xml. You can control serialization schema to some extent by use of attributes - see the MSDN link for more information.

On Sql Server side, you may use OPENXML for converting xml document to a row set that you can use to insert into tables. See [this (2000 version)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276847%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and [this (2008 version)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx) for info about OpenXml - both links contains example that should get you started.

Lastly, [Bulk Insert from XML data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184.aspx) is possible but that would typically insert data from file and I doubt if it fits into your scenario.

Comment: OPENXML is the way to shred XML in SQL Server 2000, however, in 2005 and later, the XML methods (especially .nodes()) are much preferred.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, point noted! Although, I am not Sql expert, someone had told me that OPENXML is better in bulk data (hence the suggestion). Quick search on google yield a divided opinion - would love if you/others shade some light. A link saying such (documentation or perf analysis) would be even plus!

Comment: AFAIK, the performance is similar, however the XML methods are much more flexible and capable.

Comment: I saw a performance comparison where the performance was similar (I can't find the link now). I think the issue is with memory usage and scalability: "The combination of nodes() and value() functions use XML indexes effectively. Thus, this combination can exhibit greater scalability than OpenXml." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345115%28v=sql.90%29.aspx